# Embedding Google Docs (-like) functionality

Tags: gwt, google-docs, vaadin

I'm looking for a way to embed Google Docs itself--or a Google Docs-like real-time collaboration of text documents--into a web platform built with Vaadin on top of Google Web Toolkit. Currently our users won't be creating Google IDs and, ideally, we wouldn't need them to (if embedding Google Docs itself). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Could you embed the document in an iframe as [shown here](http://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.embedded.html)? (in 5.17.3 Browser Frames)

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a text editor, another solution can be to embed tinymce within you GWT client:
http://tinymce.moxiecode.com

We did it on our project and it works perfectly